# What is the method to convert the data into NaN, if the flag in a designated column (matches top 6 letters) is "1"?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, flags

What is the method to convert the data into NaN, if the flag in a designated column (matches top 6 letters) is "1"?

There are Dataframes which indicate the data and flags.
Order of columns are different between two dataframe.

Those frames have hundreds of columns and a half a million number of records.

```
df
                    123456.A  123456.B  ... 456789.A 456789.B
2016-01-01 00:00         5.6       0.3  ...      6.7      1.1
2016-01-01 00:01         5.4       0.4  ...      6.7      1.3
2016-01-01 00:02         5.1       0.2  ...      6.7      1.5
....
2016-12-31 23:57         5.7       0.4  ...      6.7      1.2
2016-12-31 23:58         5.6       0.3  ...      6.7      1.4
2016-12-31 23:59         5.4       0.4  ...      6.7      1.5

flag_t
                      456789    123456  ...   342546   821453
2016-01-01 00:00           1         0  ...        0        0
2016-01-01 00:01           0         0  ...        0        0
2016-01-01 00:02           1         1  ...        0        0
....
2016-12-31 23:57           0         1  ...        1        1
2016-12-31 23:58           0         0  ...        0        1
2016-12-31 23:59           0         0  ...        0        1
```

This is a table that I would like to get:

```
df
                    123456.A  123456.B  ... 456789.A 456789.B
2016-01-01 00:00         5.6       0.3  ...      NaN      NaN
2016-01-01 00:01         5.4       0.4  ...      6.7      1.3
2016-01-01 00:02         NaN       NaN  ...      NaN      NaN
....
2016-12-31 23:57         NaN       NaN  ...      6.7      1.2
2016-12-31 23:58         5.6       0.3  ...      6.7      1.4
2016-12-31 23:59         5.4       0.4  ...      6.7      1.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `split` columns by `'.'`
- `add` `df2.where(df2 == 0)`

  - will be zero where zero and np.nan else where.
  - I do this because I can `add` at a specific level, broadcasting over the rest.

---

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)

df = df.add(df2.where(df2==0), level=0)

df.columns = df.columns.map('.'.join)

print(df)

                     123456.A  123456.B  456789.A  456789.B
2016-01-01 00:00:00       5.6       0.3       NaN       NaN
2016-01-01 00:01:00       5.4       0.4       6.7       1.3
2016-01-01 00:02:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2016-12-31 23:57:00       NaN       NaN       6.7       1.2
2016-12-31 23:58:00       5.6       0.3       6.7       1.4
2016-12-31 23:59:00       5.4       0.4       6.7       1.5
```

Comment: Seeing answers like this one is always fun because it reminds me of how much API surface `pandas` has that I still have never used. Interesting stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) which create `NaN` where `True` values with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
#convert columns to MultiIndex
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
print (df)

                 123456      456789     
                      A    B      A    B
2016-01-01 00:00    5.6  0.3    6.7  1.1
2016-01-01 00:01    5.4  0.4    6.7  1.3
2016-01-01 00:02    5.1  0.2    6.7  1.5
2016-12-31 23:57    5.7  0.4    6.7  1.2
2016-12-31 23:58    5.6  0.3    6.7  1.4
2016-12-31 23:59    5.4  0.4    6.7  1.5

#create new MultiIndex with flag_t columns and possible letters
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([flag_t.columns, ['A','B']])
print (mux)
MultiIndex(levels=[['123456', '342546', '456789', '821453'], ['A', 'B']],
           labels=[[2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])

#reindex flag_t by new MultiIndex mux
flag_t = flag_t.reindex(columns=mux, level=0)
print (flag_t)
                 456789    123456    342546    821453   
                      A  B      A  B      A  B      A  B
2016-01-01 00:00      1  1      0  0      0  0      0  0
2016-01-01 00:01      0  0      0  0      0  0      0  0
2016-01-01 00:02      1  1      1  1      0  0      0  0
2016-12-31 23:57      0  0      1  1      1  1      1  1
2016-12-31 23:58      0  0      0  0      0  0      1  1
2016-12-31 23:59      0  0      0  0      0  0      1  1
```

```
#create mask by reindex, cast to bool 
mask = flag_t.reindex(columns=df.columns).astype(bool)
print (mask)
                 123456        456789       
                      A      B      A      B
2016-01-01 00:00  False  False   True   True
2016-01-01 00:01  False  False  False  False
2016-01-01 00:02   True   True   True   True
2016-12-31 23:57   True   True  False  False
2016-12-31 23:58  False  False  False  False
2016-12-31 23:59  False  False  False  False


df1 = df.mask(mask)
#convert MultiIndex to columns
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('.'.join)
print (df1)
                  123456.A  123456.B  456789.A  456789.B
2016-01-01 00:00       5.6       0.3       NaN       NaN
2016-01-01 00:01       5.4       0.4       6.7       1.3
2016-01-01 00:02       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2016-12-31 23:57       NaN       NaN       6.7       1.2
2016-12-31 23:58       5.6       0.3       6.7       1.4
2016-12-31 23:59       5.4       0.4       6.7       1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your second array, `flag_t` is a valid mask for your first array, to get the output you desire, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas.DataFrame.where). Here's a small demonstrative example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b':[3,4]})
>>> mask = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1], 'b': [1,0]})
>>> df.where(mask)
<<<      a    b
    0  NaN  3.0
    1  2.0  NaN
```

In this case the rub is that there are two columns you're masking, named 'A' and 'B', so they're not exactly synonymous. Here's one way to handle this:

```
df_1 = df[[c for c in df.columns if ".A" in c]]  # Get the .A columns...
           .rename(columns={c: c[:-2] for c in df.columns})  # ...remove the .B...
           .where(mask)  # And apply the mask.
df_2 = df[[c for c in df.columns if ".B" in c]]  # Ditto.
           .rename(columns={c: c[:-2] for c in df.columns})
           .where(mask)
# Rejoin to get the final result.
masked_df = df_1.join(df_2, lsuffix='.A', rsuffix='.B')
```

Comment: Yes, I want to affect conversion to all the columns in df if the column name of the top 6 letters matches.

Comment: See my modified answer.